# A Question About Looping

Tags: c++

```
while(thingA is true)
{
}
if(thingA is not true)
{
    make thingA true
    then back to looping
}
```

My question is if the looping is true it will keep looping but if it's not I will go through aonther code to make it true, after that I want it to loop again. Can I do that!?

Comment: As written above you have an infinite loop!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code block you have provided is effectively an infinite loop.  The reason is because `thingA` remains `true` through the `while` loop, until it evaluates to `false` and breaks out of the loop.  Then it is checked by an `if` statement that checks to see if it is `false` - it has to be, or the `while` loop would not have been broken.  Then you loop some more.

Just check for `thingA` being false inside an infinite loop and execute your special case logic.

Answer (score 5):

My question is, if you want to loop until something is false, then once it's false set to true and re-loop, why check the condition at all?  Why not just:

```
while (true)
{
    if (thingA is not true)
    {
        // do whatever you want 
    }
}
```

My point just being, if all you want to do is make it true and re-loop, why stop looping at all?

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing will loop forever, regardless of the value of `thingA` (you'll always end up back in the loop).  If you need to take some action when the state of `thingA` changes, then you simply need:

```
while (1)
{
    if (!thingA) { /* Some action */ }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rearranging your code in the same function, try to move common code to a separate function.  This will make your code easier to understand and the flow easier to follow.

In your case you probably want something like this:

```
void MyLoopFunction()
{
bool MyCheckVariable = true;
while (MyCheckVariable)
   {
   ...
   }
}

void SomeOtherFunction()
{
// Keep executing until infinity
while (true)
   {
   MyLoopFunction();
   // Fell out of the loop, do something else and retry
   ...
   }
}
```